# Use whereHas to find all items that doesn't have specific value (for example User and Role - get all user that does not have admin role)

Tags: laravel

I have two models, User, and Role. Each User has many roles like 'admin', 'simple-user' and so on.
I want to get all user that doesn't have 'admin' role. I know this can be solved by the Join query. But I want use "wherHas()" function.

```
User table has id, name
Role table has id, slug, name
user_role as pivot table has user_id and role_id
```

In the User model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

and in the Role model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Example query:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query){
    $query->where('slug', '!=', 'ecoyar');
  })->get();
```

sorry about my english!

Comment: You need to provide more details: how are the two models linked? what columns are in each model? Why can't you just do `$users = User::where('role', '!=', '1)->get()`?

Comment: I updated my question based on my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to query the absence of a relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$users = App\User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('slug', 'like', 'ecoyar');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me, but is it in the Laravel documentation?!

Comment: click the link :)